# Angular 16 with Firebase 9 - File Upload

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

I have an Angular 16 app with Firebase 9 and angular/fire 7.

I am trying to implement a simple file upload to Firebase storage but have been going around and around for the past 2 days facing different errors. I have looked through the docs and the angular/fire Github docs but cannot see what I am doing incorrectly. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

I have a file upload in a Contact Us component, which is in a lazily loaded module (ContactsModule) - not sure if this will make a difference to the lazily loaded module imports?

I keep on receiving the following error

> contact-us.component.ts:134 Error: Either AngularFireModule has not been provided in your AppModule (this can be done manually or implictly using provideFirebaseApp) or you're calling an AngularFire method outside of an NgModule (which is not supported).

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ContactsModule } from './components/contacts/contacts.module';
import { SharedModule } from './components/shared/shared.module';

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp, getApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { provideAuth, getAuth, connectAuthEmulator } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { provideFirestore, getFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { provideFunctions, getFunctions, connectFunctionsEmulator } from '@angular/fire/functions';
import { provideStorage, getStorage, connectStorageEmulator } from '@angular/fire/storage';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    ContactsModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAuth(() => {
      const auth = getAuth();
      if (location.hostname === 'localhost') {
        connectAuthEmulator(auth, 'http://127.0.0.1:9099', { disableWarnings: true });
      }
      return auth;
    }),
    provideFirestore(() => {
      const firestore = getFirestore();
      if (location.hostname === 'localhost') {
        connectFirestoreEmulator(firestore, '127.0.0.1', 8080);
      }
      return firestore;
    }),
    provideFunctions(() => {
      const functions = getFunctions();
      if (location.hostname === 'localhost') {
        connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, '127.0.0.1', 5001);
      }
      return functions;
    }),
    provideStorage(() => {
      const app = getApp();
      const storage = getStorage(app);
      if (location.hostname === 'localhost') {
        connectStorageEmulator(storage, '127.0.0.1', 5001);
      }
      return storage;
    }),
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

contacts.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ContactUsComponent } from '../../components/contacts/contact-us/contact-us.component';
import { ContactsRoutingModule } from '../../components/contacts/contacts-routing.module';
import { SharedModule } from "../shared/shared.module";

import { getAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { getFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';
import { getStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ContactUsComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormsModule,
        ContactsRoutingModule,
        SharedModule,  
    ],
    providers: [
    ],
})
export class ContactsModule { }
```

contact-us.component.ts

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
// import { getDownloadURL, getStorage, ref, uploadBytesResumable, uploadBytes } from 'firebase/storage'; 
// import { initializeApp, getApp, getApps } from 'firebase/app';
import { Storage, ref, uploadBytesResumable, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL, getStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage'; 
import { getApp } from '@angular/fire/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-us',
  templateUrl: './contact-us.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-us.component.scss']
})
export class ContactUsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  contactForm: any;
  emailId: string = '';
  fileName = '';
  file!: File; 

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.contactForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      ...
    });

    this.emailId = this.generateUniqueID();
  }


  generateUniqueID(): string {
    return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9) + Date.now();
  }

  onFileChange(event: any) {
    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
      this.file = event.target.files[0];

      const filePath = `emails/${this.emailId}/${this.file.name}`;

      if (this.file.size > 5242880) {
        alert('File is too large!');
        this.contactForm.get('attachment').setErrors({ 'incorrect': true });
        return;
      } else {
        this.fileName = this.file.name;
        this.contactForm.get('attachment').setValue(this.file);  // store the file in the form control

        const upload = async () => {
          try {
            const app = getApp();
            const storage = getStorage(app);
            const storageRef = ref(storage, filePath);
            const uploadTask = uploadBytes(storageRef, this.file);
            uploadTask.then((snapshot) => {
              getDownloadURL(storageRef)
                .then((url) => {
                  console.log(`Download URL: ${url}`);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  console.error(`Error getting download URL: ${error}`);
                });
            });
          } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
          }
        };
        upload();
      }
      console.log("filePath: ", filePath);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend avoid mixing firebase and AngularFire, try to focus in only one.. I would recommend AngularFire, I think it is easier to build it..

Second have you tried npm ci? I see you commented firebase imports, and I had problems with versions because firebase package was cached.

Check Permissions in firebase storage, create a new folder called public  and enable permissions

Comment: I think in the older version you could mix them fine as I had no issues but I agree, I just stick with Angular Fire now. I placed Storage in my providers and ended up restarting the whole project, which fixed the issue. I think there was an installation issue.